# Relative Path to an Image - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The relative path to an image file is shown as below in the `testng.xml`.

```
<parameter name="adverImage" value="./res/sale_sign.jpg"/>
```

And the file is located in the following res folder with the following folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

I get the following error message on the console when the project is run.

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: File not found: ./res/sale_sign.jpg
```

Also, the same code works fine when I specify the absolute path.

-- Edit --

I'm using the following method to select the file.

```
private void selectImage(String image){
    imageSelect.clear();
    imageSelect.sendKeys(image);
}
```

It will be of great help if you can help me with this

Comment: can you try  `value="res/sale_sign.jpg"` and let me know

Comment: I've tried that as well with no success `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: File not found: res/sale_sign.jpg`

Comment: can y add piece of code what you have tried

Comment: I"ve replaced the value with the above and ran the code again. Still got the given error. But when I put the absolute path it works fine.

Comment: That's why i'm asking to add your code which method you are using to get the file

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution I've added the method in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to pass the complete path of your image, then First need to get directory path (project path).

Use this method for same :

```
String projectpath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

It will give you your current project path like:

> C:\Users\narendra.h.rajput\Automation\projectName

Now append your image path in your project path

```
<parameter name="adverImage" value="/res/sale_sign.jpg"/>
```

In Code

```
private void selectImage(String image)
{
    String location= System.getProperty("user.dir");
    imageSelect.clear();
    imageSelect.sendKeys(location+image); 
}
```

The thing is same as you are giving the absolute path. Because if you see your  res/image location in your pc it will be same as above method return

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help.  Your suggestion did work with the code `<parameter name="adverImage" value="/res/sale_sign.jpg"/>`. However, will this code work if I move the project to a different location?

Comment: Sure, Where ever you move the project , `System.getProperty("user.dir");` will give you your project path